# R - what units are MCMCglmm posterior means in?

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm

my question is probably amateurish but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

In what metric are the MCMCglmm package's posterior means for

`family = "categorical"`

?

I suppose that they can't be odds ratios and probabilites as my numbers are outside their bounds. So I'm thinking – are they just basic regression coefficients conceptually equal to those obtained by lme4::glmer?

Thank you!

Comment: I had the same question a couple years ago, and luckily I remembered where I put the answer. Check out [Jerrod Hadfield's notes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf), p. 52 to get the transformation to the logit scale. I never fully understood how to interpret the coefficients output by the model.

Comment: thank you very much! So those are originally mean ICC that I have to transform to logit by the transformation. Wow.